# Converting C code to Java code

Tags: java

I was giving some c code to convert to java code.  implement three different methods of generating all N!
permutations of N elements in Java. The code I provided is my converted c code to java, I was successful up until this line of code, swap((n & 0x01) ? 1 : i, n);...in the permute3 method, Im not entirely sure what it is doing or means and i need to know how to write the equivalent in java.

```
public class Permute {

    public static final long MILLION = 1000000L;

    static int N;
    static char p[];
    static int[][] table =   { {0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 3},
                  {0, 3, 1, 3, 1},
                  {0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3},
                  {0, 5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1},
                  {0, 5, 2, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3},
                  {0, 7, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7, 1},
                  {0, 7, 8, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 2, 3},
                  {0, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1},
                  {0, 9, 6, 3, 10, 9, 4, 3, 8, 9, 2, 3}};




    public static void init()
    {
    p = new char[27];   
    p[0] = '*';

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        p[i + 1] = (char) ('A'+i);
    }


    }

    public static void swap(int i, int j)
    {
        char c;

        c = p[i];
        p[i] = p[j];
        p[j] = c;
    }

    static void printIt()
    {
        long count = 0;

        //to compare performance, comment out from here


         for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
         System.out.printf("%c", p[i]);
         System.out.printf("\n");
         //to here

        count++;

    }

    static void permute1(int n)
    {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            printIt();
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            swap(i, n);
            permute1(n-1);
            swap(i, n);
        }
    }

    static void permute2(int n)
    {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            printIt();
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            permute2(n-1);
            swap(table[n][i], n);

        }
    }

    static void permute3(int n)
    {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            printIt();
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            permute3(n - 1);
            swap((n & 0x01) ? 1 : i, n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `swap((n & 0x01) ? 1 : i, n)` is literally valid Java.

Comment: In Java that should be `swap(((n & 0x01) == 0x01) ? 1 : i, n)` or `swap(((n & 0x01) != 0) ? 1 : i, n)`

Comment: you can simply use [this](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/cplusplus_to_java_converter_details.html)

Answer (score 0):

Binary operator **&** performs bitwise multiplication (AND) of its operands in both languages.

This expression also uses ternary operator `a ? b : c;`. First, it checks value of a, if it is true, than b is returned, otherwise c is returned.

In C, integer value that != 0 is considered to be true. Java does not cast integer values to boolean.

So for your expression to work, you need to write it as follows:

```
swap((n & 0x01) != 0) ? 1 : i, n);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's interesting to know, what the expression is doing makes sense now